# Sequential numbering column update

Tags: sql-server

I have a column (line number) that I need to update with sequential numbering starting with 001.

Am I able to run an update for this?

```
Line 1  001
Line 2  002
Line 3  003
```

Etc..

Comment: post some sample data.

Comment: I basically need update table1 set next line number = previous line number + 1

Comment: Does that line number ever reset to 001? Please post the table schema.

Comment: No it will just start as line 1=  001 and end at line 751 = 751

Comment: You need to show some column, through which data can be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new identity column in your table as below-

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

This will add a new column 'ID' to your table and also fill with value starts from 1 to end (row count of the table) with incremental value like 1,2,3.... Once this is done, either you can keep the column, or taking value from this new column you can update your column LineNumber as per your required format.